# Automatically Activate Main Window in TkInter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to automatically activate the main window of a tkinter app?  I am using Yosemite on a Mac.  When the window comes up, the title bar is grayed out, and I have to click on the window before it will respond to events.  The Tk manual says that `event generate`, "Generates a window event and arranges for it to be processed just as if it had come from the window system."  I tried generating a `<Button-1>` event, but it had no effect.  The manual goes on to say, "Certain events, such as key events, require that the window has focus to receive the event properly."  I tried `focus_force`, but it didn't work either.

Is it possible to do what I want?  Is this a Mac peculiarity?  In the code below, the text changes as the mouse cursor enters and leaves the label, but the app is unresponsive until you click on the window.

```
import tkinter as tk    
root = tk.Tk()

def visit(event):
    kilroy['text'] = 'Kilroy was here.'
def gone(event):
    kilroy['text'] = 'Kilroy has left the building'
def startup():
    root.focus_force()
    root.event_generate('<Button-1>')    

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=500,height=100)
kilroy = tk.Label(frame, text="Kilroy hasn't been here.", width = 50)
kilroy.grid(row=0,column=0)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
kilroy.grid_propagate(0)
frame.grid_propagate(0)
kilroy.bind('<Enter>', visit)
kilroy.bind('<Leave>', gone)

root.after(100,startup)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how are you starting the program? Are you double-clicking an icon? Are you typing a command from a command prompt?

Comment: Typing a command in the terminal

Comment: I ran into a similar problem, the solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843698/how-to-auto-activate-a-tkinter-simpledialog-pop-up-window/40876290#40876290).

Comment: @SB87 Thanks, but this didn't work for me.  I added the line `os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "python" to true' ''')` just before `root.mainloop()` and I get the message `21:62: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set process "python" to true. (-10006)`.  I get a similar error if I write "Python" instead of "python".  The execution of the python app is unchanged.  Have I misunderstood you?